# Cube root of any fraction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove cube root of $\frac{p}{q}$ is irrational.

It was given in my test, but our teacher didn't provide any solution afterward as to how to solve it. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not true.  Let $p=81$ and $q=3$.

Comment: It can't possibly be that the cube root of any fraction is irrational. Let's say I take some nice fraction $\frac r t$, then I cube it -- getting $\frac{r^3}{t^3}$ -- that means the cube root of $\frac{r^3}{t^3}$ is $\frac r t$, which is clearly rational.

Comment: @B.Goddard I thought so. I was also thinking the same, that the question was wrong. Thank You for clarifying it.

Comment: If $p$ and $q$ are different primes, then it is true.  You might check the exact wording of the problem.

Comment: It looks a bit familiar to a question like: "Prove that the cube root of 5 is irrational". That way, if you assume it is rational and try to write the cube root of 5 a p/q, you will fail. I mean, just checking, because the problem as it stands now, makes no sense

Comment: @B.Goddard This is the exact question and I tried to prove it via contradiction. Taking it as rational. But I could not go with the process very far. :(

Comment: @imranfat I tried but since its not an actual number, the calculation is difficult and trying to make a sense out of it is proving difficult for me.

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Proof_of_irrationality_for_non-perfect_nth_power_x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p/q$ is in lowest terms, with $q > 1$, and you are looking at the $r$-th root, for $r > 1$, where you assume that not both of $p, q$ are $r$-th powers,
do essentially as is done to prove $\sqrt{2}$ isn't rational.

Assume

$\begin{align*}
\frac{p}{q}
  &= \frac{a^r}{b^r}
\end{align*}$

with $a/b$ in lowest terms. Then:

$\begin{align*}
p b^r
  &= q a^r
\end{align*}$

Now $p$ must be divisible by $a^r$ (as $b^r$ isn't), say $p = c \cdot a^r$, and $q$ by $b^r$. say $q = d \cdot b^r$. The above simplifies to:

$\begin{align*}
c a^r b^r
  &= d a^r b^r
\end{align*}$

$\begin{align*}
c
  &= d
\end{align*}$

This means that the original fraction was a $r$-th power to begin with, contradicting our assumption.

Answer (score 1):

It's... not true.

If $p = n^3\in \mathbb Z$ and $q = m^3(\ne 0) \in \mathbb Z$ and $m$ and $n$ have no factors in common, then $\sqrt[3]{\frac pq} = \frac nm$.

Example $(\frac 23)^3 = \frac {8}{27}$ and $\sqrt[3]{\frac 8{27}} = \frac 23$ which is, of course, rational.

BUT.... if $\frac pq$ is in lowest terms and if it is not the case that both $p$ and $q$ are perfect cubes (that is if neither are perfect cubes or one but the other isn't) then, yes $\sqrt[3]{\frac pq}$ is irrational.

This is actually obvious if you think about it.

If $r \in \mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt[3] r = \frac ab$ in lowest terms then $r = \frac {a^3}{b^3}$.  Now $a$ and $b$ were in lowest terms so they had no prime factors in common.  So $a^3 $ and $b^3$ have no prime factors in common.  So $r = \frac {a^3}{b^3}$ is in lowest terms.

So if $\frac pq \ne \frac {a^3}{b^3}$ in lowest terms then the cube root of $\frac pq$ can not be rational.